# Ошибка при создании Connection Pool в Glassfish

Tags: jdbc, glassfish, java, mysql

Следую [туториалу](http://computingat40s.wordpress.com/how-to-setup-a-jdbc-connection-in-glassfish). Когда заканчиваю создание пула, пытаюсь запустить пинг и получаю исключение:

```
Exception while creating an unpooled [test] connection for pool [ Test2 ], The connection could not be allocated: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 
** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 
java.net.ConnectException
MESSAGE: Connection refused: connect  
STACKTRACE:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect at
java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
```

И так далее по стеку. Драйвер для JDBC пробовал класть и в lib домена и в lib самого glassfish.